# handleclick function not working

Tags: reactjs

I have `handleclick` function but its not called when I click.

Here is the code:

```
<div className="cal">

      <input type="num" name="res" value="0" handleClick={this.handleclick}  disabled style={{height:'8vh',width:'47vh',backgroundColor:'black',color:'white'}}/><br></br>
      <input type="button" name="ac" handleClick={this.handleclick} value="AC" style={{height:'5vh',width:'12vh',backgroundColor:'#ccced1',border:'1px solid black'}}/>
      <input type="button" name="+/-" handleClick={this.handleclick} value="+/-" style={{height:'5vh',width:'12vh',backgroundColor:'#ccced1',border:'1px solid black'}}/>
      <input type="button" name="%" handleClick={this.handleclick} value="%" style={{height:'5vh',width:'12vh',backgroundColor:'#ccced1',border:'1px solid black'}}/>
      <input type="button" name="/" handleClick={this.handleclick} value="/" style={{height:'5vh',width:'12vh',backgroundColor:'#ff9100',border:'1px solid black'}}/>
</div>
```

And here is my function:

```
handleclick(e)
{    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({value:e.target.value});
    console.log('helo click fire');
}
```

Comment: `onClick={this.handleclick}`?

Comment: `fun` != `function`. We don't charge by the character, so don't be afraid to use full words / sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are binding your function to a target:

```
this.handleclick = this.handleclick.bind(this)
```

And then in your input:

```
onClick={this.handleclick}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to bind the click function.

Update your function to:

```
handleclick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({value:e.target.value});
    console.log('helo click fire');
}
```

And then in your component, you should be able to do:

```
<input type="button" name="+/-" handleClick={(e) => this.handleclick(e)} value="+/-" style={{height:'5vh',width:'12vh',backgroundColor:'#ccced1',border:'1px solid black'}}/>
```

Notice the difference between:

```
handleClick={this.handleClick}
```

and

```
handleClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}
```

You also may want to try

```
onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}
```

as I don't think `handleClick` is a valid property of an input/button.

Comment: its working but how i can get value if i clicked on button with value="2"??

Comment: i set the state as i mention above but it gives me error of unread proprty of target or something like this

Comment: Have you tried passing the event? `(e) => this.handleClick(e)`

Comment: yes     handleclick(e)
    {    

        this.setState({value:e.target.value});
        console.log('helo click fire');
    } but it gives me error like this Cannot read property 'target' of undefined and if i comment the setstate it works perfectly

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you what I mean if you have a quick look at that it should be clear.

I mean passing the event via the onClick function, e.g `<input type="button" name="+/-" onClick={(e) => this.handleclick(e)} value="+/-" style={{height:'5vh',width:'12vh',backgroundColor:'#ccced1',border:'1px solid black'}}/>`

Comment: yes i tried to pass event but it still gives me error of tagert cannot read